# Does Saitama have any friends outside the heroes ones?

Tags: one-punch-man

Outside of his heroes friends (Genos, Bang, King, Fubuki, etc.) , AFAIR Saitama is never seen in the anime with other friends. Does Saitama have any friends outside the heroes ones? Why doesnt nobody from his former heroe life appear in the series?

Comment: In the OVA, he seemed to be friends with the Tailor that made his suit. However seeing that the Tailor up and quit, I don't know if that's true anymore.

Comment: Also, while I wouldn't call them friends, he is on friendly terms with Charanko later on, who is Bang's disciple.

Answer (score 2):

I've just read one of the last chapters of the webcomic, and Tatsumaki asks him exactly this, that if he has any friends and

> when it was the last time he met with someone outside of the hero association, to what Saitama can't answer.

And Tatsumaki calls him a lonely baldy